# Get value of custom field using Javascript

Tags: soql, javascript, custom-button, leads, list-view

I am trying to make a button that shows up on the Lead List results page. In order to sync with another system properly I need to have this button basically copy the name of an Account that has a lookup relationship with the associated Lead then copy the name of that Account to another field within the Lead. My problem is that I can do a query for the ID of that Account, the query says the ID, but won't let me do anything with it.

This is what I get when I check a value:

> 00Q6100000FQiRw
>   {done:'true', queryLocator:null, records:{type:'Lead', Id:null, Partner_Owner_Account__c:'0016100000RuwBRAAZ', }, size:'1', }
>   {id:'00Q6100000FQiRwEAL', success:'true', }

This is what I have on the button, it's not done of course, but I am trying to figure out why my query reports the lookup ID, like I want, but if I try to put it into an array all it does is grab the Lead ID instead:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")}
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Lead)};
var updateRecords = [];
var result = [];

if (records[0] == null) { 
    alert("Please select at least one record to update.");
} else {
    for (var a=0; a<records.length; a++) {
        var my_Query = "SELECT Partner_Owner_Account__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = '" + records[a] + "'";
        var query_Result = sforce.connection.query(my_Query);
        result[a] = query_Result.getArray("query_Result");
    }
    result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords);
    alert(records[0] + "\n" + query_Result + "\n" + result[0]);
}
```

I don't understand this result. If the query_Result reports the ID that I want (0016100000RuwBRAAZ) why then, when I put it into an array, it gives me the ID of the Lead itself instead (00Q6100000FQiRwEAL)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes no sense, and it's wasting a lot of API calls in the process. What you're apparently looking for, so far, would look like this:

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")}
var recordIds = {!GetRecordIds($ObjectType.Lead)};
var updates = [];
if(!recordIds.length) {
    alert("Select at least one lead.");
} else {
    var qr = sforce.connection.query(
         "select partner_owner_account__c from lead"+
         " where id in ('"+recordIds.join("','")+"')");
    var leads = qr.getArray("records");
    leads.forEach(function(v) {
        var acc = new sforce.SObject("Account");
        acc.id = v.Partner_Owner_Account__c;
        updates.push(acc);
    });
    sforce.connection.update(updates);
}
```

Also, see the documentation on [Processing Results](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_results.htm) to see how this should work. Finally, when working with pure Id variables, consider using "retrieve" instead of "query", as it has better performance.

Comment: I didn't realize what a dumb mistake I was making by using "result" the way I was. I did end up switching to retrieve instead however and simplified my code considerably. It does work now, and thank you! This is still quite a learning process to me as I am very new to both Salesforce and coding in general. Again, thank you.

Comment: @mmmtacos I'm glad I was able to point you in the right direction. We all started at the bottom at some point, so don't feel bad. You'll get better with practice!